text-overflow ellipsis doesnt with symbol !!! when using with webkit
i have a css as below
div.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  line-height: 16px;
  white-space: normal;
}

with the text
no-webkit-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
then text-overflow: ellipsis will not work as expected if using display: -webkit-box;
it works perfect other if the text doesn't include symbol like !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
or remove display: -webkit-box;. but i want to keep display: -webkit-box; because i need display 2 lines which is required display: -webkit-box;
any solution will be appreciated!
here is code in the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/thanhtungka91/gvbchao1/

Add this style to your code.
line-break: anywhere;


Simple solution fixed the issue, thank you so much, even i asked chatgpt but there is no solution :D

Solution for your issue is pretty simple and straight forward add word-break: break-word to .b that's it.


div.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-word;
    line-height: 16px;
    white-space: normal;
}

  div.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
    line-height: 16px;
    white-space: normal;
}
<h2>text-overflow: clip (default):</h2>
<div class="a">no-webkit-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b">H１２６!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</div>




oh, it is simple and works, i was suprise it is also work with case
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
